# Rails session cookies

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, session, session-cookies

In Rails, How to cross check whether the session is successfully created or not on both client and server ?

index.html:

```
<body>
    <center>
    <h1> Login </h1>
    <form action='login/auth' method='POST'>
        Name:<input type="text" name="name" widht=20>
        Password:<input type="password" name="pass" widht=20>
        <input type="submit" value="submit">
        <%= tag(:input, :type => "hidden", :name => request_forgery_protection_token.to_s, :value => form_authenticity_token) %>
    </form>
    </center>
    <br><br>
</body>
```

LoginController:

```
class LoginController < ApplicationController
  def auth
    if params[:name].present? && params[:pass].present? 
        @name=params[:name]
        pass=params[:pass]

        if(@name == "admin" && pass == "admin")
            session[:id]=user.name
            render "success"
        else
            render "authfailed"
        end
    else
        render "argerror"
    end
  end

end
```

In the above controller, I create the session only when the username and password is "admin". And it properly worked and successfully renders "success"
page. But I am not able to find any session stored in the response in my browser. I check it via developer tools. So, how to cross check that
the session is created or not on both client and server.

And one more doubt is, How session is stored in server. The session variable is just looks like hash. Then how it persist and store data
accross multiple reqest. Is there any graphical diagram which shows the datastructure of session maintenance in server.

Comment: please check `config/initializers/session_store.rb` it should have `Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_your_app_session'`

Comment: @RajarshiDas session_store.rb file contains `Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_somesession'`. This is successfully stored in my browser. But the session created within my controller like session[:id], is not created in my browser.